# Use of ROW_NUMBER with nvarchar key

Tags: sql, sql-server, key, row-number, nvarchar

I've recently been assigned a project by a former colleague involving synchronizing SAP inventory information using SQL Server as backend over the web. Part of it involves generating XML files - and here is where my dilemma lies.

In the XML structure I have to follow, each inventory item is contained in a `Message` element with a numeric ID, kinda like this:

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <first item />
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <second item />
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

The `MessageID` field serves as a row number: it increments from 1 to the number of the rows in the result set. Problem is, the table's primary key is `nvarchar` but `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY )` requires a `bigint` key, so the following code:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY items.ItemCode) MessageID,
    items.ItemCode as SKU
FROM OITM items
FOR XML PATH('Message'), ROOT('Messages')
```

fails with

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Casting `ItemCode` to `bigint` isn't possible because the key contains non-numerical characters in almost all rows. There are no other key fields in the table either and adding one by hand is not feasible because:

1. There are 5500+ rows in the table.
2. SAP does not support its tables being subjected to an `UPDATE` on the SQL backend and locks the database if it detects inconsistency.

I cannot alter the XML structure either because then the API on the other side won't accept it.

So my question is: is there any way to use `ROW_NUMBER()` with an `nvarchar` key? Or an alternative to `ROW_NUMBER()` that works with non-numeric keys?

Comment: I've just tried your code and have no problem generating the required XML, what is giving you the error message. Adding some sample data would help too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user states the question raised in error.  See their answer.

Answer (score 1):

...d'oh, that error was being given by a completely different line. I'm blind as well as dumb, it would seem.

Feel free to rate the question down because *I fully deserve it*.

Comment: Happens to all of us once in a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `row_number()` to a string:

```
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY items.ItemCode) as VARCHAR(255)) as MessageID,
       items.ItemCode as SKU
FROM OITM items
FOR XML PATH('Message'), ROOT('Messages');
```